# Не собирается iio модуль

Tags: c++, linux, kernel, модули

Разбираюсь в libiio, пытаюсь написать условный Hello world модуль (упростил до одной строчки)

```
#include <iio.h>
static struct iio_context *ctx;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ctx = iio_create_default_context();
    return 0;
}
```

Мой Makefile:

```
obj-m += iio_first_steps.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Пишу make и мне выдает ошибку :

```
/home/name/iio_dir/iio_first_steps.c:2:10: fatal error: iio.h: Нет такого файла или каталога #include <iio.h>
```

Нагуглил все, что только можно, и linux-headers обновлял и пытался добавлять руками iio.h в /usr/include/linux - ничего не сработало. Причем если пытаться это дело компилировать в обычный объектный файл .o, то iio.h  видно.
Прошу вашей помощи или каких-нибудь советов

Comment: А где у вас команды компилятору?

Comment: `gcc -o iio_first_steps.o iio_first_steps.c -liio`

Comment: Вы нигде не указываете местонахождение заголовочного файла `iio.h`, для этого необходимо добавить аргумент `-I`

Comment: В make файле ? Сделал вот так `make -I /usr/include/ -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(shell pwd) modules`. Все равно тоже самое пишет

Comment: в том файле, в котором указываются остальные аргументы для gcc

Comment: Так вы в **библиотеке** пытаетесь разобраться или в **подсистеме ядра**?

Comment: @VTT, там всё гораздо запущеннее...